# Is this the right way to write Redux reducer?

Tags: redux

This is my reducer code, please let me know this is the correct format the reducer should be ?

I am a newbie to Redux please help me with this problem. I have gone through the documentation but i didn't get the context of this, if i am wrong please let me know where i am wrong

Below is my reducer code.

```
export default createReducer(initialState, {

[SELECT_ENTITY]: (state, data) => {

let selectedEntity;

if (data.isSection) {

// Assert the section exists
selectedEntity = state.sections.filter(section => section.id ===     data.entityId)[0];

} else {

const lectures = state.sections.reduce((acc, section) => {

return (acc.concat(section.lectures));

},[]);

selectedEntity = lectures.filter(lecture => lecture.id === data.entityId)[0];

}

let newState;

let propertyWindowIsActive;

if (state.propertyWindowIsActive) {

if(state.entity.id === data.entityId  &&  state.isSection ===  data.isSection) {

// propertyWindowIsActive = false;

newState = Object.assign({}, state, {propertyWindowIsActive: false, entity:{}, isSection: null});

} else {

// propertyWindowIsActive = true;

newState = Object.assign({}, state, {entity: selectedEntity, isSection: data.isSection});

}

} else {

// propertyWindowIsActive = true;

newState = Object.assign({}, state, {propertyWindowIsActive: true, entity: selectedEntity, isSection: data.isSection});

}

return (newState);

}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Please carefully format your code when posting questions. Even after copying and pasting your code into a text editor and fixing up the alignment, it doesn't appear to be valid JavaScript.

Since you're new to Redux, I suggest you avoid wrappers like "createReducer". Just write your reducers as pure functions. They should always have two parameters `state` and `action` and return the new state. Your reducer should have a switch statement based on `action.type`.

Please read the Redux docs on reducers.
http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html

Comment: Thanks David for the reply, So you are saying that i can't use the logic inside the reducer, there will be only swich case which checks the action and returns the state.

Comment: You will certainly use logic in the reducer.